# Getter returns undefined in if statement. Seems not working for comparisons

Tags: javascript, undefined, getter

I have a ClockObj which has an AlarmObj in a "HAS A" OOP relationship. Or should I say injected through the constructor.

Inside the AlarmObj I have a isAlarmOn boolean variable. I am returning it using getter.

```js
class AlarmObj {
  isAlarmOn = true
  get getAlarmOnOffStatus() {
    return this.isAlarmOn;
  }
}

class ClockObj {

  constructor(AlarmObjArg) {

    this.AlarmObj = AlarmObjArg

    if (this.AlarmObj.getAlarmOnOffStatus === true) {
      console.log('works')
    }
  }
}

AlarmObj = new AlarmObj();

new ClockObj(AlarmObj)
```

However it return undefined and when debugging I found that getter is called after the if statement.
Is that normal behavior or something is wrong here ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: This line `AlarmObj = new AlarmObj();` is very bad, because you overwrite the global class variable with an instance. It may be causing issues

Comment: @Konrad I am not sure I understand. Will it be different If I name them `class AlarmClass` and then `AlarmObj = new AlarmClass();`
Because in reality this what I did. Here was a simplified example. In any case - Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this structure based on your description and it works

```js
class AlarmObj {
  isAlarmOn = true
  get getAlarmOnOffStatus() { return this.isAlarmOn; }
}

class ClockObj {
  AlarmObj = new AlarmObj()
  
  constructor() {
    if (this.AlarmObj.getAlarmOnOffStatus === true) {
      console.log('works')
    }
  }
}


new ClockObj()
```

Comment: I am sorry to bother you with this question but I am trying to find a way to answer you with a code snipped of my own but I can't.

The only difference is
class ClockObj {

  constructor(AlarmObj) {

this.AlarmObj=AlarmObj;

    if (this.AlarmObj.getAlarmOnOffStatus === true) {
      console.log('works')
    }
  }
}

  AlarmObj = new AlarmObj()
new ClockObj(AlarmObj)

Comment: This would get `AlarmObj is not a constructor`. Could you try editing your question and adding the snippet?

Comment: @ILIIACHTEREV, can you not edit your question and either use a stack snippet or another code block, i tried it in a jsbin and it still works, https://jsbin.com/besomekobu/edit?js,console, its the only thing i can see wrong with your answer is they said they had passed it through the constructor

Comment: @Konrad I tried to edit my question and the mess got bigger. Seems using Stackoveflow is beyond my brain capacity. Yet the code is still visible. I got another answer with another working example. But this is what happens to me. I can upload the debugging process on youtube !!

Comment: @matt richards I am repeating for you - I tried to edit my question and the mess got bigger. Seems using Stackoveflow is beyond my brain capacity. Yet the code is still visible. But this is what happens to me. I can upload the debugging process on youtube !!

Comment: did you check out the link to the jsbin i left earlier, i could edit your question for you but i feel as you posted similar code to this users answer i would be stepping on his toes

Comment: @ILIIACHTEREV, you can chat further on stackoverflow chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript if you like

Comment: @mattrichards I tried that jsbin link and it work fine. But again this what happens on my side. I debug it VS 2019 and Chrome and in both cases it does this. Seems the only proof would be to screen record the debugging. I do not know however if I would be allowed to post youtube link. I can  not use that chat as I do not have sufficient reputation. And I can not see further benefits from it. In any case - Thank you for trying.

Answer (score -1):

My bad. Yes, the getter was returning undefined but that was because the variable itself was undefined. I did not check it because I assumed that if the debugger calls the getter after the comparison this was the problem. It turns however that this is the normal behavior.